# javascript reqular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am looking for an alternative to the C# Split where I can pass an array of strings.

```
string[] m_allOps = { "*", "/", "+", "-", "<", ">", "=", "<>", "<=", ">=", "&&", "||" };
string s = "@ans = .707 * sin(@angle)";
string[] tt = s.Split(m_allOps,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);      // obtain sub string for everything in the equation that is not an operator
```

I'm sure there is a solution using regEx but I can't seem to figure out how to construct the regular expression.

Comment: What do you want as output ?

Comment: @ans,.707,sin(@angle) for this case

Comment: See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xtsoLpvd/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get an `escape` extension method (to use the .NET term) on the RegExp prototype: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/18771

Then:

```
var m_allOps = ["*", "/", "+", "-", "<", ">", "=", "<>", "<=", ">=", "&&", "||"];
var splitPattern = new RegExp( m_allOps.map(RegExp.escape).join('|') );
// result: /\*|\/|\+|\-|<|>|=|<>|<=|>=|&&|\|\|/

var s = "@ans = .707 * sin(@angle)";
var tt = s.split(splitPattern).filter(function (item) {
    return item != "";
});
// result: ["@ans ", " .707 ", " sin(@angle)"]
```

where the filter function is the replacement for `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: `.filter(function (item) {
    return item != "";
})` can be replaced with `.filter(Boolean)`.

Comment: Yes, probably. It's rather un-obvious though.

Comment: I'm getting this error  JavaScript runtime error: Array.prototype.map: argument is not a Function object.  But that is ok, I'll just use the literal splitPattern

Comment: What browser are you on? `Array.prototype.map` (etc) should be available on [any reasonably modern browser](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Array_methods); the list of supporting browsers goes down to IE9. If it is not available on your platform, consider including [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/), which adds these kinds of methods.

Comment: @Tomalak It's not `Array.prototype.map` he's missing, it's `RegExp.escape`.

Comment: \*sigh\* You're right. I *literally* only have two sentences of text in my answer.

Comment: @MtnManChris You really have copy-pasted my code and have not read a single word of the text I wrote, haven't you? o_O

Comment: @Tomalak.  Wrong, The question was how to construct the regEx expression.  You supplied that with this "result: /\*|\/|\+|\-|<|>|=|<>|<=|>=|&&|\|\|/".  Although @ torazaburo decided my English wasn't sufficient and did correctly point out that RegExp.escape was what was missing.

Comment: @MtnManChris So what does the first sentence of my answer say? You still did not read it.